# Is reassigning a virtual function legal

Tags: c++, inheritance, function-pointers, virtual

Suppose I have a class like this:

```
struct A{
  virtual void someFunc() { }
};
```

Is it possible to reassign the virtual function to another function....This might be possible because it basically stores a function pointer in the class so that it can be `virtual`.

I realize that something like this:

```
void aRandomFunc();
A mya;
mya.someFunc = &aRandomFunc;
```

Is probably impossible because member functions take a `this` pointer as an implicit parameter.

But is it possible to reassign a member function to another member function?

Comment: Why? Did you find a compiler that allows this and are wondering if it is standard C++?

Comment: @juanchopanza Just curious...haven't actually written any code yet

Comment: "it basically stores a function pointer in the class" - not quite. Vtable implementations store a pointer to a table of function pointers, but that table is shared between all objects of the class.

Comment: @aschepler That is probably a more space efficient way to do it then I had in my mind

Comment: There might not be a vtable. The vtable is a common solution to virtual functions, but not one required by the standard.

Comment: Please review the difference between a pointer to a function and a pointer to a member function.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

No, there are no circumstances under which a function may be reassigned.

You can, however, reassign a function pointer, but whether this will be useful depends on what you are actually trying to do. https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem

Comment: Not to forget the opportunity to exchange whole abstract interfaces at runtime. Very useful to provide State Pattern implementations.

Answer (score 3):

No, it is not possible to re-assign a function.

You can do 2 things to get a different function behavior:

1. Use a function pointer.
2. Inherit from this class and override the function.

It is likely that neither of these ways are an elegant solution to the problem you have.

---

An example of a function pointer might be:

```
struct A{
  virtual void (*pSomeFunc)(void);
};

...

A a;
a.pSomeFunc = &aRandomFunc;
a.pSomeFunc();
```

---

An inheritance example might be:

```
struct AWithDifferentFuncAbility : public A {
    virtual void someFunc() {
       //some new functionality;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you should try `std::function`, it does something close to what you need.

Here's how you can do it with this class:

```
struct A{
  std::function<void()> someFunc = []{ /* default implementation */ };
};
```

And then you can change what function it is later:

```
void aRandomFunc();
A mya;
mya.someFunc = &aRandomFunc;
```

Or even replace it with another lambda:

```
mya.someFunc = []{ /* another function */ };
```